# Pandas apply function to column and fill 2 columns from function return

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose i have a following dataframe

```
| domain           | category | confidence  

| www.test.com.    |          | 

| www.someurl.com  |          |
```

I want to apply `my_func` to domain column. This function return tuple with two values, i want to fill category and confidence with those values for every row.
Something like  `df['category', 'confidence'] = df['domain'].apply(my_func)`

The result i expecting is

```
| domain           | category       | confidence  

| www.test.com.    | test-category  |   0.5

| www.someurl.com  |  some-category |   0.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return `pd.Series`. For example:

```py
cnt = 0


def my_func(x):
    global cnt
    cnt += 10
    return pd.Series(["something {}".format(x), cnt])


df[["category", "confidence"]] = df["domain"].apply(my_func)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            domain                   category  confidence
0    www.test.com.    something www.test.com.          10
1  www.someurl.com  something www.someurl.com          20
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the current pandas version you can do that with `result_type='expand'`. from the pandas  [apply documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
>>>df.apply(lambda x: [1, 2], axis=1, result_type='expand')
   0  1
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
```

And the solution from @Andrej Kesely is also there stated:

Returning a Series inside the function is similar to passing `result_type='expand'`. The resulting column names will be the Series index.

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1, 2], index=['foo', 'bar']), axis=1)
   foo  bar
0    1    2
1    1    2
2    1    2
```